# Como alterar paginador alfabético e numérico?

Tags: php, mysql

Como posso alterar esse código para que funcione da seguinte forma ele no caso coloca as letras iniciais de cada item adicionado em $aIniciais ai caso clique ele filtra listando todos os itens com aquela letra inicial com tudo números, caracteres e símbolos ele também insere eles de forma individual fazendo aparecer eles na lista de links em $iniciais gostaria de uma forma de fazer um link único para identificar todos os itens com números e caracteres ai caso fosse clicado lista-se todos os itens não iniciados por letras do Alfabeto.

Como posso fazer isso ?

```
<table width='400' align="center">
<tr>
<?
mysql_connect("localhost","usuariobanco", "senhabanco");
mysql_select_db("bancodedados");

$db = "tabela";
$coluna = "coluna";

$Consulta = mysql_query(" SELECT UPPER(LEFT($coluna, 1)) inicial FROM $db GROUP BY inicial  ORDER BY inicial") or die (mysql_error());
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($Consulta)) {
$aIniciais = $rs["inicial"];
$v = "<font style='font-family: Verdana,Tahoma,Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif; font-size: xx-small; '>
      <a href='?inicial&ini=$aIniciais'> $aIniciais</a></font>" ;

printf(" <td>| $v</td> ");
}

?>
</tr>
</table>

<?
$inicial2 = $_GET['ini'];

$conta = mysql_query("select * from $db WHERE LEFT($coluna,1) = '$inicial2' order by $coluna ASC") or print (mysql_error());
$total = mysql_num_rows($conta);

// inicio paginação

function f_paginacao ($tr,$rpp,$pg) { // $tr eh total_records e $rpp eh registros por pagina
$inicial2 = $_GET['ini'];
  if ($tr%$rpp==0){$pages = intval($tr / $rpp)-1;} else {$pages = intval($tr / $rpp);} // calcula quantas paginas serao necessarias
  if ($tr>0){
     echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Total de Registros Encontrados: <b>$tr</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp; ";
     $NumRegistroInicial = ($pg*$rpp)+1;
     if ($pg <> $pages) {$NumRegistroFinal = ($pg*$rpp)+$rpp;} else {$NumRegistroFinal = $tr;}
     echo "Exibindo Registros de <b>$NumRegistroInicial</b> a <b>$NumRegistroFinal</b>";
     echo "<br>";
     echo "<p align=\"center\">Páginas:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
     if ($pg <> 0) {
       $showpage = $pg - 1;
       echo '<a id=mulink href="'.$PHP_SELF.'??inicial&ini='.$inicial2.'&pg=0">Primeiro</a>&nbsp;';
       echo '<a id=mulink href="'.$PHP_SELF.'??inicial&ini='.$inicial2.'&pg='.$showpage.'">Anteriores</a>&nbsp;';
     }
     for ($i = $pg-5; $i<$pg; $i++) {
        $showpage=$i+1;
        if ($i>=0) {
           echo '<a id=mulink href="'.$PHP_SELF.'?inicial&ini='.$inicial2.'&pg='.$i.'">'.$showpage.'</a>';
           echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        }
     }
     for ($i = $pg; ($i<=$pages AND $i<=($pg+5)); $i++) {
        $showpage=$i+1;
        if ($i == $pg) {
           echo '<font face=Arial size=2 color=0000FF><b>'.$showpage.'&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></font>';}
        else {
           echo '<a id=mulink href="'.$PHP_SELF.'?inicial&ini='.$inicial2.'&pg='.$i.'">'.$showpage.'</a>';
           echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
        }
     }
     if ($pg < $pages) {
        $showpage = $pg + 1;
        echo '<a id=mulink href="'.$PHP_SELF.'?inicial&ini='.$inicial2.'&pg='.$showpage.'"> Próximas</a>';
        echo '<a id=mulink href="'.$PHP_SELF.'?inicial&ini='.$inicial2.'&pg='.$pages.'"> Último</a>';
     }

  }
}
// FINAL DA FUNÇÃO DE PAGINAÇÃO

$dbname=""; // Indique o nome do banco de dados que será aberto
$usuario=""; // Indique o nome do usuário que tem acesso
$password=""; // Indique a senha do usuário
//1º passo - Conecta ao servidor MySQL
$id = mysql_connect("localhost",$usuario,$password);
//2º passo - Seleciona o Banco de Dados
$con=mysql_select_db($dbname,$id);
//3º passo - Contar os registros da tabela
$sql_tr= mysql_query("select COUNT(*) as total from $db WHERE LEFT($coluna,1) = '$inicial2' ");
$res_tr= mysql_fetch_object($sql_tr);
$tr=$res_tr->total;  //tr total de registros

if (isset($_GET[rpp])) {$rpp = $_GET[rpp];} else {$rpp = 50;} // $rpp é registros por pagina - o padrao é 10
if (isset($_GET[pg])) {$pg = $_GET[pg];} else {$pg = 0;}
$inicial = $pg * $rpp ;




$sql = "select * from $db WHERE LEFT($coluna,1) = '$inicial2' order by $coluna ASC LIMIT $inicial,$rpp";
$res = mysql_query($sql,$id);
f_paginacao($tr,$rpp,$pg);
?>

<center>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%" align="center">
<?

if($resultadoposter = mysql_num_rows($conta)) // VERIFICA RESULTADO
{

$i = 0; // define o $i como 0 pra ter um ponto de partida pra coluna
echo "<tr>"; // inicia a pimeira linha

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

$poster  = $row[""];    // ainformar a coluna da tabela entre as aspas
if($i == 2) // se ja tiver impresso as colunas
{
$i = 0; // reseta a contagem
echo "</tr>"; // quebra a linha com tr

} // IF i == Coluna

$i++; // e sempre adiciona +1 pra $i que significa a contagem

print("<td><font face='Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='1'>$poster</font></td>");


} // WHILE RST RST_SELECT
echo '</tr></tr>';


} // IF RST_SELECT


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pra fazer o índice, pode ajustar desta forma:

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT($coluna,1)) AS inicial
WHERE
   UPPER(LEFT($coluna,1)) >= 'A' AND
   UPPER(LEFT($coluna,1)) <= 'Z'
FROM $db GROUP BY inicial ORDER BY inicial
```

Podia ter usado um *regex* no lugar, a query ficaria menor, mas tecnicamente usar *regex* pra esse tipo de coisa é o mesmo que abrir gabinete de PC usando faca de ponta. Assim como na parte seguinte, se você usar o *collation* *latin-1* *insensitive*, não precisa dos UPPER e vai funcionar com acentos e sem.

Outro detalhe: Nâo esqueça de por manualmente o símbolo para outras iniciais. O Tal '-', ou mesmo '#' no índice, para que a pessoa pesquise o resto das coisas.

Uma possível solução pro problema de pesquisar de A a Z ou outros caracteres:

```
$inicial = strtoupper( $inicial );

if( $inicial < 'A' || $inicial> 'Z' ) {
   // se a inicial não é de A a Z, pesquisamos tudo que não comece por letra
   $where = " LEFT( $coluna, 1 ) < 'A' OR LEFT( $coluna, 1 ) > 'Z' ";
} else {
   // senao, pesquisamos pela inicial
   $where = " LEFT( $coluna, 1 ) = '$inicial' ";
}

$conta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db WHERE $where ORDER BY $coluna ASC") ;
```

Desta forma, se a inicial for de A a Z, o resultado é buscado pela inicial, senão é buscado por tudo que não comece por letras A a Z. Dependendo do *collation*, pode ser necessário `UPPER( LEFT ( ... ) )` para trabalhar com minúsculas e maiúsculas. Se estiver com *latin-1* *insensitive*, não precisa se preocupar nem com acentos.

Comment: Valeu cara eu consegui colocar o código funcionando da forma que eu queria graças a você muito obrigada pela ajuda.